# Textmesh - Pixelperfect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm want to create pixel perfect text meshes using unity's built in 3d textmesh, without using any other plugins. Since dynamic text is texture based as well, there should be a ratio between *font size*, *text size* and *orthogonal camera size* to make it pixel perfect.

I know that its not possible to make built-in 3d textmesh pixel perfect for perspective cameras since text size (and texture atlas size) will be effected from the perspective scale; however for orthogonal cameras that should be possible.

Online sources does not state the connection between the ratios I mentioned above; most of the people I've spoken do not really *care* about making text pixel perfect. However I do think it's very important especially if dynamic text is going to be used in a 2d game, and needs to *fit* to screen pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be pixel perfect, the only solution would be to use GUI text. If, however, you expect to animate it in a way that can't be done with OnGUI, or intend to partially cover the text with another object, I would recommend cranking up the font size, and the scale down. This will at least make the text very sharp, making it appear pixel perfect. I have used a font size = 100 and scale = 0.05 for x y and z in a 2D game to achieve a very clear and easy to read font.

Comment: In both cases, there should be a relation between the values I stated above.
Getting a sharp result and pixelperfect result are different things.